# Summarizing a matrix. Obtaining mean values for each 100000 units class

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following data structure.

```
pos <- c(4532568,4541529,4586529,4591235,4712360,4732504,4740231,10532655,10542365,10564587,45312567,45326354,45369874,124832658,124845829,124869874)
cm <- c(2.21,2.25,2.26,2.29,3.31,3.35,3.36,4.32,4.35,4.39,5.23,5.27,5.29,7.36,7.45,7.49)
data <- cbind(pos,cm)

            pos   cm
 [1,]   4532568 2.21
 [2,]   4541529 2.25
 [3,]   4586529 2.26
 [4,]   4591235 2.29
 [5,]   4712360 3.31
 [6,]   4732504 3.35
 [7,]   4740231 3.36
 [8,]  10532655 4.32
 [9,]  10542365 4.35
 [10,]  10564587 4.39
 [11,]  45312567 5.23
 [12,]  45326354 5.27
 [13,]  45369874 5.29
 [14,] 124832658 7.36
 [15,] 124845829 7.45
 [16,] 124869874 7.49
```

My intention is to summarize rows grouping by 100000 units in column "pos" and obtaining the mean value of column "CM" for each class.
The outcome in this example would be like the following:

```
pos <- c(4500000,4700000,10500000,45300000,124800000)
cm <- c(2.2525,3.34,4.35333,5.26333,7.43333)
newdata <- cbind(pos,cm)

           pos      cm
[1,]   4500000 2.25250
[2,]   4700000 3.34000
[3,]  10500000 4.35333
[4,]  45300000 5.26333
[5,] 124800000 7.43333
```

I don't know how to automatize the process to deal with a huge data frame.

Answer to Akrun:
So. If I use the following script in my real dataset:

```
 Ch1<- ch1 %>%
 as.data.frame %>% 
 group_by(Pos = plyr::round_any(Pos, 1e5, f = floor))
```

Then I get the following outcome (just the first 10 lines)

```
 structure(list(Chr = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "1", class = "factor"), Pos = c(0, 0, 0, 
 2e+05, 5e+05, 5e+05, 5e+05, 5e+05, 5e+05, 7e+05), CM = c(0, 0.080572, 
 0.092229, 0.439456, 1.478148, 1.478214, 1.480558, 1.488889, 1.489481, 
 1.931794)), .Names = c("Chr", "Pos", "CM"), row.names = c(NA, 
 -10L), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), vars = "Pos", drop = TRUE, indices = list(
 0:2, 3L, 4:8, 9L), group_sizes = c(3L, 1L, 5L, 1L), biggest_group_size = 5L, labels = structure(list(
 Pos = c(0, 2e+05, 5e+05, 7e+05)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame", vars = "Pos", drop = TRUE, .Names = "Pos"))
```

However, If I use the whole script to get the mean values of the Ch1$CM:

```
 Ch1<- ch1 %>%
 as.data.frame %>% 
 group_by(Pos = plyr::round_any(Pos, 1e5, f = floor)) %>% 
 summarise(cm = mean(cm))
```

Then I get the following data.frame:

```
 structure(list(Pos = c(0, 2e+05, 5e+05, 7e+05, 8e+05, 9e+05, 
 1e+06, 1100000, 1200000, 1300000), cm = c(4.528498, 4.528498, 
 4.528498, 4.528498, 4.528498, 4.528498, 4.528498, 4.528498, 4.528498, 
 4.528498)), .Names = c("Pos", "cm"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
 "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

As you can see the mean values are wrong, since all of them are equeal. I don't know why this is happening.

Comment: `aggregate(dat[, "cm"], list(floor(dat[,"pos"]/1e5)), mean)`

Comment: Thanks a lot, user20650. It works perfectly. However, I would also need to get the variable pos like in "newdata".

Comment: just multiply it by `1e5` ie `aggregate(dat[, "cm"], list(pos=1e5* floor(dat[,"pos"]/1e5)), mean)` . for bigger data `data.table` might be faster ie `setDT(as.data.frame(dat))[, lapply(.SD, mean), by=1e5* floor(pos/1e5)]` .  These approaches are the same used as akrun's nice answer - it just shows how to create the groups, perhaps, a bit more explicitly.

Answer (score 6):

We can use `round_any`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
    as.data.frame %>% 
    group_by(grp = plyr::round_any(pos, 1e5, f = floor)) %>% 
    summarise(cm = mean(cm))
# A tibble: 5 x 2
#        grp       cm
#      <dbl>    <dbl>
#1   4500000 2.252500
#2   4700000 3.340000
#3  10500000 4.353333
#4  45300000 5.263333
#5 124800000 7.433333
```

Comment: Sorry akrum! But I can't get the correct result in my real dataset. I will answer my question with the results I get when I do apply your script... I hope you can help me further.

Comment: @Cisco Perhaps you have NA, then use `mean(cm, na.rm = TRUE)`  or if the values are really big, then you may need to use specialized packages like Rmpfr or gmp to get the accuracy

Comment: As you can see below, the first part of the script works nicely, the problem is with the mean of the variable CM by the groups.

Comment: I don't have any NA. The dataset is 280000 rows. I believe it's not too big.

Comment: In summary, group_by() works perfectly, but not the summarise()

Comment: @Cisco  May be try with `%>% dplyr::summarise(cm = mean(cm))`  IT could be that you have also loaded plyr and the `summarise` from that library masked the function